# Getting a highlight colored icon from jQuery UI as bullet point?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

In my jQuery themebuilder built theme I have 5 different ui-icons_* files.
Two of them are in an orange shade corresponding to the highlight color.
I want to use an orange icon as a bullet.

My first attempt gives the icon on it's own row.

```
<div class="heading">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e" ></span>
    Meeting
</div>
```

My second attempt gives the icon but not aligned properly.

```
<div class="heading">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e" style="display:inline-block"></span>
    Meeting
</div>
```

Adding the following style makes the text align with the icon:

```
.heading { vertical-align: top; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rypyP/1/

The color i want is in the ui-state-active set, so if I add that state to the containing unit it gets the correct color, but with the whole enchilada (border, background color, text color) and I just want the bullet point orange.

```
<div class="heading ui-state-active">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e" style="display:inline-block"></span>
    Meeting
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MEXQV/1/

**Can I get *just the icon* from a particular ui-state in a jQuery theme without rewriting the css?**

If that is not possible, what way would you suggest and why?

**SOLUTION**

Stylesheet:

```
.heading
{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="heading">
    <span class="ui-state-active" style="border: 0px">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e" style="display:inline-block; border: 0px">
        </span>
    </span>
    Meeting
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rypyP/4/

Comment: You want list elements using your jQuery UI imagery as bullets but these elements don't have any jQuery UI connection otherwise?

Comment: Why not use the jQuery UI theme image and otherwise provide your own styles for this list? Would allow you to mark it up properly and probably save you a lot of pain.

Comment: @polarblau I think that's what I'm asking how to do.

Comment: I see. Sorry that I didn't get that right away, but I've a feeling I might have not been the only one.

Comment: @polarblau I just want to do it with the least amount of duplicate code and resources. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get the icon of a particular ui-state, you can do this:

```
<div class="heading">
<span class="ui-state-active ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e " style="display:inline-block"></span>
Meeting</div>
```

What it does is it will look the specified icon on jQuery's default theme icon set (it has four icon sets by default -- active, default, highlight, and error). If you want to remove the borders etc, you'll have to override the ui-state class in your own css, e.g: adding `.ui-state-active { border: 0px; }`

Thanks.

Comment: I've tried this also before asking, but what happens is that I get a misaligned image with 2 partial icons in it.

Comment: I needed to put another span with the ui-state-active outside the ui-icon span. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rypyP/3/
I'm marking your answer as the correct answer anyway. Thanks! :)